# Set initial state using local/session storage in react application

Tags: reactjs, state, session-storage

I want to initiate my state using local/session storage. Is this approach valid? I tried but it gives me an error. If not, then how can I retrieve a value from the storage directly to my state?

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
      sessionStorage.setItem('testkey','test value')
      this.state = {
            abc: sessionStorage.getItem('testkey')
       }
}
```

The error is always undefined.

Also, if I use the other way around, below code works fine

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
      this.state = {
          abc: this.getItems(val)
      }
     this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
}

getItems(value){
   let selectedItem =  value;
   return selectedItem;
}
```

But when I do this, it doesn't. I just cannot get the value from my session storage.

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
          this.state = {
              abc: this.getItems(val)
          }
         this.getItems = this.getItems.bind(this);
    }



 getItems(val){
       let setItem = sessionStorage.setItem('testkey', val);
       let getItem = sessionStorage.getItem('testkey');
       return getItem;
    }
```

When I log getItem to my console, it gives me an object. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: remove semicolon after `abc: sessionStorage.getItem('testkey');`

Comment: In your example you can just set the abc state to the test value. There is no benefit writing it to the storage. But say, you get the value from somewhere else then you can set it like that in a function and get in your constructor. Then your approach would be valid.

Comment: What error did you get? Which line caused the error?

Comment: I have updated the question, please check and sorry for the delay.

Comment: why dont you just update a property value in state?

Comment: I have tried. Doesn't work either. The problem persists when I am trying to retrieve the value from sessionStorage.

Answer (score 1):

Im still not too sure what you mean but you definitely have to use this.setState().

this function accepts json {'key':'value'}
once set it updates the state.
You dont actually have to store a function within a state.

I dont know if this was a thing where you use getters and setters.
Set variable values using setState then retrieve them using this.state.[variable_name].

Hope this helps.

```
class Session extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    this.state = {};
  }

  setValue(key, value){
    let data = {};
    data[key] = value;
    this.setState(data);
  }

  render() {
    let session = this.state.session;
    return (
      <div >
        <div>{ session }</div>
        <input onClick={ ()=> this.setValue('session','Hello') } type="button" value="Click Me" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Session;
```

Happy coding.